# PHP/SQL:Data from DB don't show

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a form for a project that when the user insert their username and click submit their info will show in the respected area (with some ajax).The problem is the data show only the column name and the rest are empty. I have insert all the info needed in the table, but still data don't appear.
Below is my PHP code:

```
<?php
require "co.php";
$link = mysqli_connect($h,$u,$p,$db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

$q = "select * from login where User_name ='".$_GET['name']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$q);
if($result){
echo "<table border='1' >
<tr>
<td align=center> <b>user Id No</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Name</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Password</b></td>
<td align=center><b>responsibility</b></td></td>";

while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{   
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align=center>$data[0]</td>";
echo "<td align=center>$data[1]</td>";
echo "<td align=center>$data[2]</td>";
echo "<td align=center>$data[3]</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}

else{
echo ' Failed';
}
?>
```

And also i include html code:

```
html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#display").submit(function(e) {   
     e.preventDefault();

 $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
    type: "POST",
    url: "tesz2.php",
    data: { name: $('.name').val() }, // set the naem variable             
    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
    success: function(response){                    
    $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
    //alert(response);
             }

           });
      });
   });

 </script>

<body>
<form method =POST action=test2.php id="display">
<input type ="text" class='z' id='name'><br>
<input type='submit'>
</form>


<h3 align="center">Manage Student Details</h3>
<!--table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
   <td> <input type="button" id="display" value="Display All Data" /> </td>
</tr>
</table-->
<div id="responsecontainer" align="center">

</div>
</body>
```

Can anybody tell me what the error or maybe some solution. Thanks

Comment: Sidenote: You really quote these `<form method =POST action=test2.php`. Some browser don't like it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so what should i use?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking; "use" what? I only gave you a "sidenote", which isn't fully directed at solving your question. If you have errors, you should check for them.

Comment: @Fred -ii- i know that not the answer.. I just curious what the other subtitute for the code if some browser can't run that.

Comment: From what I can see is that you're using `class='z'` yet you're using `$('.name')` which you may have confused yourself with the id `id='name'` - those need to match. Either you use the `z` class by renaming your `$('.name')` to `$('.z')`  or change your `class='z'` to `id='name'` and `$('.name')` to `$('#name')`. But I think the best would be to change `data: { name: $('.name').val() }` to `data: { name: $('#name').val() }`; try that. My JS is very limited.

Comment: Yet here is a problem I know about for sure; being this `mysql_fetch_row`  - That `mysql_` function does not work with a `mysqli_` connection. You need to use `mysqli_fetch_row()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i will try that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional javascript function `displayData()` which can be used for displaying all data.

```
function displayData(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'tesz2.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
      'perform': true,
    },
    success: function(data){
      $('#responsecontainer').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

In your `php` file you have to do:

```
if(isset($_POST['perform'])==true){
  //Query........
}
```

Now add call this function ajax function `success`.

```
$.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
  type: "POST",
  url: "tesz2.php",
  data: { name: $('#name').val() }, // set the naem variable             
  dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
  success: function(response){
    displayData(); //All data will show                 
    $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
           }

         });
    });
 });
```